# Why does Chrome not show a selected <option> element after using the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a `<select>` tag that contains a single `<option>` element:

```
<select id="someselect">
  <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

The single `<option>` is later replaced using jQuery. The new list of options always contains the old option:

```
selected = $('#someselect').val();
$('#someselect').html('<option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option>').val(selected);
```

This works as expected. However, when navigating away from the webpage in Google Chrome and then clicking the back button, something weird happens. The select tag is back to its initial state (makes sense), but the single `<option>` element is not selected!

What is the cause of this behavior in Chrome?

I've created a minimal working example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27566470/backdemo.html
Initially there is only a single `<option>`. First click on "click" to replace the options (but keep the 'B' option selected), then click on "Google" to navigate away, and then use the back button of Chrome to see the `<select>` tag with only a single option that is not selected.

Edit: to clarify, I'm not interested in how to fix this. I'm curious why Chrome works like this. Serving the original (unmodified) DOM after using the back button makes sense, but why is the only select option not selected?

Comment: you click back, your page gets `refreshed`, you can get it by using `GET` method in `URL` and make a progress or
`sessions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems to be a Chromium bug. I've filed a bug that is currently confirmed and triaged: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125509
So hopefully this should be fixed in the future :)

Comment: Adding autocomplete="off" attribute to form fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Because when browser back button is used it use the cache version of page but in your page there is dynamic data which got lost so browser does not find the previously selected value, You can set it by using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#someselect').val('0');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because every browser that navigates outside the document (# is still inside) when navigates back they load the server cached version, and that said Chrome modifies the DOM when you select an option taking away the `selected` attribute to the selected option element and when you get back it loads again with the `selected`

Comment: But the thing is, when using the back button it DOES NOT select the original selected element (it selects nothing). When using a normal refresh on the website, everything works as expected.

Comment: nope, when the user go back manually the DOM load with the `selected` property on `B`

Comment: Yes, the option tag has a selected property, but is not selected: that is the problem. Firefox caches the whole modified DOM (so with options  'a' AND 'b') and shows that. Chrome shows the original DOM, but it does not select the original option.

Comment: The original `DOM` only has one option, is called `B` and is `selected` by default. Firefox when you go back gets the latest version of the web with `A` and `B`, but Chrome doesn`t: Chrome gets the cached server version of the web, and thats why Chrome brings only one option on the select: `B` and it comes `selected` Just like the server told to Chrome. Chrome, at least on Mac and Windows (the two I could try) do what I told you.

Comment: That's exactly what I said about the Firefox part. But with Chrome: it indeed has only one option, but it is not selected here when I go back (after modifying the DOM). Tested on Windows and Linux using Chrome 18.

Comment: OK, these are my tests now only on Windows (not Mac anymore today) and these are my sshots [Pre testing](http://i47.tinypic.com/r10wt4.png), [After clicking `click`](http://i46.tinypic.com/316n6ad.png), and finally after [clicking Google and going back](http://i45.tinypic.com/29frwxi.png). Thats what me with the latest Chrome (18.0.1025.162 m) get trying your link. In fact I remember on Chrome for Mac the selected does not has any value, just the attribute (pretty fair) and on Windows has the value, maybe Chrome for Linux is different, but Windows 7 shows this

Comment: Ohh, ok ok ok,  now I see what we were doing different, I was clicking always on `A` and you don't. Correct, Chrome does not selects `B` when going back if you don't click anything between tests... But the `selected` attributes is still there, annoying. Can you add some checkboxes and form elements with default values to test?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10570/discussion-between-david-diez-and-intru)